# How to inset html styling into PHP return email

Tags: php, html, email

Right now I'm storing all my info into a variable

```
$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "<b>Name:</b>" . $name . "\n";
$email_body = $email_body . "E-mail:" . $email . "\n";
$email_body = $email_body . "Phone Number:" . $phnum . "\n";
$email_body = $email_body . "Message:" . $message . "\n";

$messageSend = $email_body;

mail($to,$subject,$messageSend,$headers);
```

How do I add in html like `<br/>`, `<b>` tag and css?

Comment: thanks I will refer from there

Answer (score 2):

Append to headers `Content-Type` like

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
```

And append message `<html><body>` and `</body></html>` like

```
$email_body = '<html><body>';
$email_body .= "<b>Name:</b>" . $name . "\n";
$email_body .= "<b>E-mail:</b>" . $email . "\n";
$email_body .= "<b>Phone Number:</b>" . $phnum . "\n";
$email_body .= "<b>Message:</b>" . $message . "\n";
$email_body .= '</body></html>';
```

Answer (score 0):

"\n" does not work in html use "paragraph" tag like this

```
$email_body = "<html><body>";
$email_body .= "<b>Name:</b>" . $name . "<p>";
$email_body .= "<b>E-mail:</b>" . $email . "<p>";
$email_body .= "<b>Phone Number:</b>" . $phnum . "<p>";
$email_body .= "<b>Message:</b>" . $message . "<p>";
$email_body .= "</body></html>";
```